# Finding Officejet 8600's bulit-in RAM

Tags: memory, printers, hp

Before I give away my dead HP Officejet 8600 Pro for recycling, I want to ensure that no memory remains on it. Even after extensive research, it's not easy to find conclusive information on whether a home printer retains memory or not (and if it does retain, how much). Supposedly the printer has 64 MB of built-in RAM, but when I crack open the printer and look at the circuit-board I do not see anything that looks like RAM or memory storage. Does anyone know where it is or what it would look like?

Comment: RAM is no permanent memory. If it is not powered it looses all information within a few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The printer is an inkjet printer. Many inkjet printers don't have memory that can be replaced, serviced or expanded by the user. The memory of the Officejet 8600 is fixed 64 MB, so it is soldered to the printer's mainboard directly and you can't remove it.

IMHO the RAM chip is this one:

[image: RAM chip on a HP Officejet 8600 mainboard]

The nature of RAM is that it looses its contents as soon as it's powered off, so you needn't worry about RAM much.

You can try to destroy it physically, e.g. by lifting it off with a screwdriver or unsoldering it with a hot air pistol, but IMHO that's overkill.

However, many inkjet printers can also print from Flash cards, SD cards, USB sticks or other permanent memory. Check that no such disk is left in the printer.